# How many 8 digit numbers are there which are both divisible by 18 and every digit is either a 1, 2 or 3?

Tags: python, math, numbers

Solving this problem using python involves making sure that all the individual digits of numbers between 10,000,000 and 99,999,999 are 1, 2 or 3 and if the numbers are also divisible by 18. The answer (win) is the number of times both these conditions are true.

This is what I have so far:

```
count=10000000
win=0
yes=False
while(True):  
    def check():
        i=0
        for i in range(0,7):
            if count[i]==1 or count[i]==2 or count[i]==3:
                yes=True
            else:
                return(False)
        return(yes)

    while True:

        if count%18==0 and check()==True:
            win+=1



    print(win)
    count+=1
    if count>99999999:
        exit()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question "Any help is greatly appreciated" is too vague. What exactly are you asking us? Just what is the problem with your code? Does it give an error message or return a wrong result or take too long or something else? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question and get good answers. Also, is an answer done completely or mostly by mathematics acceptable?

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. use a `for` loop and `range()`.. 2. don't test every number, start at 10,000,008 (the lowest 8-digit multiple of 18) and increment by 18. That way you are never looking at a number that isn't 8 digits and a multiple of 18, and don't have to test for either of those. 3. You can end at 40,000,000 since you know that all numbers after that will have a digit that isn't a 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: you almost for sure need to figure it out without actually looping (ie mathematically)

Comment: Just complementing @kindall suggestions: you can convert a number to string with `str(n)` and strings are iterable, that means you can apply the built-in function `set` to reduce it to a list without any repetitive apparition of ti's digits (a mathemathical set).

Answer (score 6):

You can try this.
Looks simpler for me.

```
count=0
for i in range(*number_after_11111111_which_is_divisible_by_18* ,33333333, 18):
    for j in str(i):
        if int(j) not in [1,2,3]:
            pass
        else:
            count+=1
print(count)
```

The range starts from the first number after 11111111 which is divisible by 18 and goes on till 33333333 incrementing 18 at once and check if the number contains any non [1,2,3] values and increments the count.

And you can filter out only from 11111111 to 33333333 as there wont be any number completely containing 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: Your `if` statement won't work because `j` is a string and your list contains integers. Instead do `if j in "123"` and do away with the `else`.

Answer (score 4):

total number of values divisible by 18 between 10000000 and 99999999

is equal to

total number of values divisible by 18 between 0 and 99999999 minus the number of values divisible by 18 between 0 and 10000000

`ttl_in_range = (99999999//18 - 10000000//18) = 5000000`

---

the total numbers that consist of all 3's,2's,and 1's = 3 choices per spot for 8 spots = `3**8 = 6561`

---

you can quickly see its far quicker to iterate over only the all values and ignore the other ones

you can find all of the values in this range with itertools product

```
ct = 0
for val in itertools.product("123",repeat=8):
    if int("".join(val))%18 == 0:
       ct += 1
print(ct)
```

the answer appears to be **267** values are 8 digit numbers divisible evenly by 18 consisting entirely of 1,2,3 digits

**@MBo's answer below is much much faster than this answer :)**

Comment: FYI takes 5ms on my computer :)  Nice!

Answer (score 2):

We can avoid both brute-force and composing from digits. Just apply some logic, math, combinatorics:

Number that contains 8 digits from range 1..3 and is divisible by 18, must be ended by digit 2 (`xxxxxxx2`)  - to be even.

Now we have 7 digits with sum 7 or 16 (to provide divisibility by 9 for full number).

Explanation:
Number is divisible by 18 if it is even and divisible by 9.
Numbers, divisible by 9, have digit sum 9,18,27...
27 is too high for 8-digit number with max digit 3, so possible digit sums are 9 and 18.
If we subtract 2 (last digit), then sum of 7 first digits is 7 or 16

We can make sum 7:

- from 7 ones - **1** variant

We can make sum 16:

- using two 3's and five 2's  - C(7,2) = **21** variants
- using three 3's and three 2's  - C(7,3)*C(4,3)=35*4=**140** variants

*(explanation : there are 7 places, there are nCr(7,3) or C(7,3) variants - number of combinations - to place three 3's and C(4,3) variants to place three 2's to free 4 places)*

- using four 3's and one 2'  - C(7,4)*C(3,1)=35*3=**105** variants

Overall number of variants is 1+21+140+105 = **267** variants

Comment: well played sir! I wish i had your math skills

Comment: lol thanks you !  great answer ! this is amazing to me really and makes me feel small minded:P (although i now understand all the parts of how it works)

Comment: @Joran Beasley Explanation added to answer

Comment: @Joran Beasley But this problem has very specific limits. It's not easy to formalize approach and apply it to similar cases.